# How to start an activity from not-activity class and wait until it is finished?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, synchronized

I am working on an Android library which starts it's own Activity. I need to have library's method working synchronously, it means I want to wait until the started Activity is done and then return a value. How can I do it? I tried different approaches and nothing seems to do what I want.

This is the librairy's method starting an activity:

```
    @Override
    public Response admin(TypeEnumeration type) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        i.putExtra("type", type.value());

        context.startActivity(i);

        Response response = NewActivity.getResponse();
        return response;
    }
```

The activity starts many different fragments and waits from user's interaction.

I don't want to use active waiting for `NewActivity.getResponse()` not to be null. I tried adding an extra object to use `wait()`/`notyfy()` on it but then the activity was not starting at all.

Any tips will be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: what is response?

Comment: onActivityResult() ?.. Question is little bit confusing..

Comment: "I need to have library's method working synchronously" -- why do you think that you "need" to do this? Asynchronous APIs (callbacks, listeners, futures, RxJava-style observables, etc.) are very common.

Comment: This a client's requirement: they want to call a library's method and have theirs application blocked until the result comes.

Comment: Use a 'MyApplication 'class that extends `Application` class and set a singleton or field inside the class. You can set status values inside the MyApplication class to check status and value. You can get this value and state of the Activity from whichever activity you wish.

Comment: Then get rid of the activity. Or, better yet, get rid of the client. For example, what happens when you start `NewActivity`... then the user navigates away from the app entirely (HOME, `Notification`, overview screen, incoming phone call, etc.)? Or, what happens when the user uses the overview screen to return to the client's application (which is in a separate task), ignoring `NewActivity`?

Comment: @FatihOzcan This is an android library, I don't want to extend `Application` because someone using the library might not want it. Also, I would have to activity wait for the answer, right?

Comment: @alicjab, i know it's an Android library, you extend Application class and create a new class with name 'MyApplication' and  `<application
        android:name="com.yourcompany.MyApplication">` inside you manifest file. Now, every class and fragment can get fields or objects with this. I use this to use Bluetooth reading in each activities that has a singleton Hanlder or use a Volley request avilable to all activites to set priority

Comment: That new class has nothing to do with your library. It's a general class to exchange info synchronously between activites. I get bluetooth info in MainActivity and get it from the LibGDX game started from MainActivity, also use it to set priority for my Http request depending on which activity send them using a singleton `RequestQueue`

Answer (score 1):

The most common scenario (which is what yours sounds like) is when a child Activity is used to get user input - such as choosing a contact from a list or entering data in a dialog box. In this case you should use startActivityForResult to launch your child Activity.

This provides a pipeline for sending data back to the main Activity using setResult. The setResult method takes an int result value and an Intent that is passed back to the calling Activity.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
// TODO Add extras or a data URI to this intent as appropriate.
resultIntent.putExtra("some_key", "String data"); 
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

To access the returned data in the calling Activity override onActivityResult. The requestCode corresponds to the integer passed in in the startActivityForResult call, while the resultCode and data Intent are returned from the child Activity.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  switch(requestCode) {
    case (MY_CHILD_ACTIVITY) : {
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // TODO Extract the data returned from the child Activity.
        String returnValue = data.getStringExtra("some_key");
      }
      break;
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I use `startActivityForResult` when I start the activity from a library, not from another activity?

Comment: which library you are using?

Comment: My library, the one I am working on and the one what starts the activity and waits for a result :)

Comment: boss I am asking library name.that what you are using?

context variable available there how it comes

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why would you need a name of my library?

Comment: just check that library i am asking

is that fragment. or any Android component?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourNewActivity.class);
    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, ResponseCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented the same sort of thing a few days back. Just follow the below provided step for the same:

1. Use the application reference (can get using activity.getApplication()) and register for activity lifecycle callbacks using: 
   `application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
   callback)`
2. Now open the activity as you were doing earlier.

    `context.startActivity(i);`
3. Store the data that you want to pass from opened activity; in some variable that will stay after activity got killed. It can be some static reference in your library, some member variable in the object that has a lifetime more than the activity or persistence storage like shared preferences.
4. Now close your activity using `activity.finish()`.
5. At this time your previous activity will get resume and you will get a call in activity lifecycle method i.e `onActivityResumed(Activity activity)`
6. Enjoy!